# Failing in the patching of a python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a problem with mocking functions outside classes in unittest.
Let's say that my project looks like that:

[image]

file a.py:

```
class A:

    def func(self):
        raise NotImplemented


def func2():
    raise NotImplemented
```

file test_a.py:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from code.a import A, func2


def test_good():
    with patch(
            'code.a.A.func',
    ):
        a_obj = A()
        a_obj.func()  # patching is working fine, no error


def test_bad():
    with patch(
            'code.a.func2',
    ):
        func2()  # getting Value error -> patching isn't working
```

When I am mocking method inside the class everything is ok, but when I try to do it with function outside class It does not patch it.
I would be grateful for your help.
I am using python 3.8.

Comment: You have to patch the function where it is used, in your case it is locally and not in the `code.a` module. But in general patching things locally makes less sense in tests, so you might have a conceptual error in your tests.

Comment: `func2` and `code.a.func2` are two different references to the same underlying function. You are patching the *latter* name, but using the *former* name in the test.

Comment: Ok thanks, you right, when I import the whole module like: 'from code import a' and then I use function like: a.func2() it seems to be ok.